# Handling unique dynamic login pages in ASP.NET MVC (Architecture)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm working on a school project where I have to implement a ticket processing system at a national level. The scenario is that there are multiple ticket booths that can log in throughout the united states. For this project i'm required to create a dynamic login screen which will load a picture of that ticket booth at login. So when the user goes to the web page, it must know which booth the user is attempting to login from, and must then also grab an image and set it as the background for the login page.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and also I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, just to help me come up with a solution that I could implement.

Edit: I probably don't want to do anything with IP addresses because they are not reliable. So far geolocation through JS seems like a good idea and a default login which then stores a cookie for the login location also seems like a good idea.

Comment: If those booths have some `on-location` configuration, the only thing the person who deploys it would have to do, is setting the start page of the browser to include the booth's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approach (i know it does not full fit to your needs):

What about the scenario if a ticket booth visits the website for the first time, there's a dropdown menu (with all ticket booth locations) shown + login form, and a checkbox with "remember my decision" ?
After successfully logged in a cookie will be stored on the computer which saves the country decision, that for any following visit of the website you could load the specific image.

Comment: I should've mentioned this but the ticket booths are not allowed to see each other in any way throughout the application. But what I do like is the idea of having a default login page, once the user logs in it can check the db for the location of that user and store an Id for the background image associated with that location. So upon initial login it would be empty, then while the cookie persists, it would load the background image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IP address of the Phone Booth and depending on it, set a different background image.

In order to get the client IP address in ASP.NET you could use the [`Request.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. You could then have a mapping between IP addresses of phone booths and images and pick the appropriate image.

Answer (score 0):

The chief problem you're going to have here is that *before* a user logs into your site, you have very limited information about them, and *all* of that information is unreliable as it can be spoofed very easily.

If you can do this by location, the best method may not even be your MVC stack, but actually a bit of frontend JavaScript. You can use the Geolocation API to get the user's physical location and then use that information with an AJAX call to fetch the appropriate background image from an API endpoint.

However, given that this is assignment, the requirement might be to only use the backend, in which case, there's not much you have available to you other than the IP address. Again, this information can be easily spoofed, or otherwise garbled. Proxy servers, frontend caching servers, etc will all cause the IP to originate from that server rather than the actual user's IP. VPN can also mutate the IP, hiding the user's true location.

Even if you do get the actual true user IP, it's often only regional: the range is tied to a server at the state the user is in (not necessarily the actual city the user is in), and in some cases, it might even just be a nearby state. If your booths are fairly spread out and not concentrated densely in any one area, you might be able to properly determine the background image to show just by general region, though.

Frankly, the assignment sounds a little half-baked, so you might want to go back to your instructor to get a better sense of the requirements.

Comment: I really like that idea because it would be the most accurate, I'm gonna e-mail the instructor to see how he thinks we should go about handling this. Thank you